# Ionic 4 transparent ion-content

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass, ionic4

I have an Ionic 4 app and I want a transparent content.

This does not work and always the content white. I have added this to the css as well:

```
ion-content{
  --ion-background-color: transparent;
}
```

[image]

Comment: `ion-content {
   --background-color: transparent;
   --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
 }`

Comment: sorry Péttrin it does not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ionic contents background is set with the `--background` scss variable
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/content

`ion-content { --background: transparent;}`

Comment: Any way this can be done programmatically (e.g using jQuery)?

Comment: This is also not working for me.